# Ember Direct URL findQuery returns entire store rather than single record

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This should be simple but am struggling. Found the following post to get my query by a slug to work.  [EmberJS Direct Slug URL Access Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808404/emberjs-direct-slug-url-access-not-working)

Works when navigating from a link-to however according to the above post, the model returned should be a single record array when accessing directly. Then I should just be able to return the first object of the array. However my entire store is getting returned. All subcategories. The slug is unique on each record so it should only return one subcategory. All the data and relationships are loading according to the Ember inspector (data tab shows it all there)

**Here is a JSBin of the code below. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qajawopovo/3/edit?html,js,output**

> Error: Assertion Failed: ArrayProxy expects an Array or Ember.ArrayProxy, but you passed object

Here is my route code:

```
App.Router.map(function () {    
      this.resource("section");
      this.resource('subcategory', { path: "/section/:slug" }, function () {       
          this.resource("record", { path: ":id" });
       });
}); 


App.SectionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        Ember.Logger.warn("Inside section route");       
        return this.store.find('subcategory'); // gets all subcategories perfectly      
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        this.controller.set('model', model);
        this.controllerFor('sectionnav').set('model', model); //set section nav to list of subcats
    }
});


App.SubcategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function (params) {
         Ember.Logger.warn("Passed Param: " + params.slug);
        return this.store.find('subcategory', { slug: params.slug });
    },
    serialize: function (model) {
        //ANOTHER POSSIBLE ISSUE? THIS IS BEING HIT MULTIPLE TIMES....up to 20 when on PREVIOUS route And 13 times when going to this route directly in url address. THere are 5 subcategories total. With many records.  Why?? 
        Ember.Logger.warn("Serializing in subcategoryroute");
        return { slug: model.get('slug') };
    },  
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
          //If the model comes from a link-to helper it will be an object, if it comes from the route it will be an array of one element
          //model is the entire store rather than the one record when going to the route directly. WHY??
         if (Ember.isArray(model)) {                  
            this.controller.set('model', model.get('firstObject'));            
         } else {
            this.controller.set('model', model); //this works fine from link-to
         }       
        themodel = this.store.find('subcategory');
        this.controllerFor('sectionnav').set('model', themodel);
}
});
```

Here are the models (included the embedded records in case these are the cause):

```
App.Subcategory = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    slug: DS.attr('string'), 
    records: DS.hasMany('record', { embedded: 'always', async: true })
});
Ember.Inflector.inflector.irregular("subcategory", "subcategories");

App.Record= DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    comments: DS.hasMany('comment', { embedded: 'always', async: true }),
    events: DS.hasMany('event', { embedded: 'always', async: true })
});

 App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
     title: DS.attr('string')        
 });

 App.Event = DS.Model.extend({
     name: DS.attr('string'),        
     eventdates: DS.hasMany('eventdate', { embedded: 'always' })
 });

 App.Eventdate = DS.Model.extend({  
     eventDate: DS.attr('string'),
     startTime: DS.attr('string')

 });
```

Data (I am working with a RESTAdapter but here is the subcategory data in FIXTURES):

```
App.Subcategory.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, name: "First Category", slug: "firstcategory", records:[1,3]},
    {id: 2, name: "Second Category", slug: "secondcategory", records:[2] },
    {id: 3, name: "Third Category", slug: "thirdcategory", records:[5,6] },
    {id: 4, name: "Fourth Category", slug: "fourthcategory", records:[4] },
    {id: 5, name: "Fifth Category", slug: "fifthcategory", records:[7,8] }
];
App.Record.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, name: "Record One", comments: [1], events: [1,2]},
  {id:2, name: "Record Two", comments: [2,3], events: []},
  {id:3, name: "Record Three", comments: [4], events: [3]},
  {id:4, name: "Record Four", comments: [], events: []},
  {id:5, name: "Record Five", comments: [6], events: [4]},
  {id:6, name: "Record Six", comments: [], events: []},
  {id:7, name: "Record Seven", comments: [7], events: []},
  {id:8, name: "Record Eight", comments: [], events: []}   
];
App.Comment.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, name: "Comment One"},
  {id:2, name: "Comment Two"},
  {id:3, name: "Comment Three"},
  {id:4, name: "Comment Four"},
  {id:5, name: "Comment Five"},
  {id:6, name: "Comment Six"},
  {id:7, name: "Comment Seven"},
  {id:8, name: "Record Eight"}  
];

App.Event.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, name: "Event One", eventDates: [1]},
  {id:2, name: "Event Two",eventDates: [2,3]},
  {id:3, name: "Event Three",eventDates: [4]},
  {id:4, name: "Event Four",eventDates: [5]} 
];

App.Eventdate.FIXTURES = [
  {id:1, eventDate: "4/5/2015", startTime: "07:00"},
  {id:2, eventDate: "6/9/2015", startTime: "08:00"},
  {id:3, eventDate: "5/15/2015", startTime: "15:00"},
  {id:4, eventDate: "3/25/2015", startTime: "14:00"},
  {id:5, eventDate: "4/5/2015", startTime: "11:00"},
];
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance. PLEASE let me know if I need to include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My debug version of Ember is giving me this on the console: on your fiddle

Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'records' relationship on a 'subcategory' with id 2 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (`DS.hasMany({ async: true })`)